# the solution of linear DE when the auxiliary equation have repeated roots

Tags: differential

I have heard that the solution of nth order linear homogeneous DE of constant coefficient is expressed as
e^mx, xe^mx, (x^2)e^mx, ... , (x^(k-1))e^mx
when the auxiliary equation have repeated roots of k multiplicity.

But how can we prove it?
I searched it for 4 hours...But I can't find the proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, checking these are solutions: for $n\ge 1$

$$\frac{d}{dx}x^ne^{mx}=nx^{n-1}e^{mx}+mx^ne^{mx}$$

So,

$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}-m\right)x^ne^{mx}=nx^{n-1}e^{mx}$$

$$\implies\left(\frac{d}{dx}-m\right)^nx^ne^{mx}=n!e^{mx}$$
Therefore, $\left(\frac{d}{dx}-m\right)^kx^ne^{mx}=0$ for $k>n$, so $e^{mx},xe^{mx},...,x^{k-1}e^{mx}$ are all solutions to $\left(\frac{d}{dx}-m\right)^kf=0$. Moreover, they are linearly independent as the monomials $x^i$ are themselves [linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510041/proving-linear-independence-of-infinite-set-monomials).

Now, the solution set of an order $k$ linear ode has dimension $k$, so our set of $k$ linearly independent solutions must in fact be a basis.

Comment: thanks a lot! it helps me really